# Deleting the standard welcome message after a time

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

Say I'm trying to be a good moderator and patching up some broken windows, but I don't want to trounce upon the hard work of all the people who have taken time to do the important job of going through the review queue and greeting new users to the site with the standard welcome message.

Still, it seems a bit strange to have a "welcome" 2 years hence.  So, how long after the initial greeting does "welcome" become an obsolete comment,  or should it never be considered that?

Comment: Related: [Are “Welcome to Christianity SE” comments helpful?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3868/21576)

Comment: I don't see how this is a problem.  There isn't something that needs fixing, from my PoV.  *Dos centavos* donated.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it hurts to leave the welcome messages. They indicate that the user was new here *at the time.* It's not as though we're posting new welcome messages to users who have been here for two or three years actively asking and answering questions.

These welcome messages also give a general friendly feel to the site when people are browsing through various questions and answers. (Assuming the welcome messages are actually friendly, and not snarky—in which case, zap 'em!)

If, however, a welcome message points out a problem in the question or answer that has since been fixed, then it might be best to delete it as "obsolete."

Answer (score 3):

There's some relevant advice on Meta.SE:

1. [Should "Welcome to [site]" (and nothing else) comments be flagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237522/299342)

All the answers to that question are upvoted and advice ranges from

- [It depends on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237537/299342)
- [Yes, flag and delete them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237525/299342)
- [There's no problem with them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237523/299342)

That question doesn't necessarily involve *old* "welcome" comments, though.

2. [When should I flag a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237980/299342)

> When it will be shown to future readers but offers them nothing of value.

By that metric old "welcome" comments should be deleted. The same post says that such comments are "too chatty", and specifically addresses old comments:

> - **too chatty** comments might be polite, friendly, even informative - but they have nothing whatsoever to do with the post!...these are pretty benign - right up until they're being shoved in the face of every reader two years later.

3. [When should moderators delete comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237982/299342)

> Same advice as for flaggers: when they offer nothing of value to either the author of the post or to future readers.

---

Personally, **I don't see any harm in leaving old "welcome" messages as long as they aren't hiding other, more useful comments.** A similar practice is advocated on Meta.SE for "thanks" comments:

> You shouldn't feel obligated to flag them when they are not distracting from anything else. When it distracts from other comments (*especially* if other comments are hidden as a result or take up more than a small fraction of the height of a page), I think they should be flagged.
>
> <sub>[Answer to "Should a “thank you” comment be flagged?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169999/299342)</sub>

I follow that practice on the site I moderate ([Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)) when I see such comments during regular browsing. If the comment is *flagged*, however, my community has decided that such comments should be deleted. *This* community doesn't seem to have a problem with these comments (judging from the votes and comments on this question), so if that's the case you can decline flags on old "welcome" comments.